# React: Calling window.print after setstate doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, printing, styles, setstate

I want to print the page on a click, however I don't want to print the header and the button on the page:

```
<DetailedSummaryContainer id="detailedSummaryContainer">
        {!this.state.printMode ?
                <Header className="container">
                <HeaderText>Header Text</HeaderText>                    
                <ButtonContainer>
                    <StyledButton onClick={this.print}>Print</StyledButton>                        
                </ButtonContainer>
            </Header>
            : null
        }            
        <PrintableArea>
            ...
        </PrintableArea>
</DetailedSummaryContainer>
```

So when clicked on Print, I want to change the printMode to true, so it rerenders the dom and then print the new dom, and then when the print preview is shown, and then I set the printMode to false again.

```
print = () => {
        this.setState({ printMode: true }, () => 
        {
           console.log(this.state.printMode); 
           window.print();
         });
    }
```

For now I didn't set the printMode to false yet.
What happens with this code is that the state is changed to true, the page is rerendered and the header and button are not shown, but instead of opening a print preview a `about:blank` new tab is opened.

The reason I want to keep the `DetailedSummaryContainer` tag is I want the styles to be applied. Otherwise I would add a ref to `PrintableArea` and do this:

```
print = () => {
        var printContents = this.printComponent.innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;        
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

In this method the print works perfectly, but the style is only from `PrintableArea`, I need the styles from `DetailedSummaryContainer` to be applied too.

If there is a better way to do so, I can take another approach.

Comment: can't you ref the DetailedSummaryContainer? i mean, if you're in printmode the header stuff isn't part of the innerHTML (since it's null)

Comment: @rebecca YESS! that worked, thanks! do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my comment:

you can put the ref on the `DetailedSummaryContainer` instead of `PrintableArea` 
since you're Header is `null` when in printmode and not part of the innerHTML, so it's not conflicting with what you want and you get to keep the styling

Answer (score 1):

I suppose setting the `printMode` back to `false` after `window.print` is just what you want. Note that `window.print` prevent the whole javascript process from running

```
  click = () => {
    this.setState({ printMode: true }, () => {
      window.print();
      this.setState({ printMode: false })
    });
  }
```

try:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ywbl1g?embed=1&file=index.js

Comment: The new blank tab problem doesn't happen, but I am not sure why some of the stuff are missed in the page, when I do this.

Comment: still can not figure out why you choose `ref` over `state`. Try the link provided, isn't it what you want? @Andi

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned for some reason, it doesn't work in our code. We aare using Kendo Gauge and the label inside the gauge is just disappearing when I try the method you provided which seems very reasonable. So the answer to your question is that the one that I chose worked for me, this one didn't. But your answer might help someone else!